# Impossible to activate Duet AI despite receiving provisioning email

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ai

I signed up for the Duet AI preview and received two confirmation emails, the last one stating that all I needed to do now was to set it up in the cloud console. However, every time I try to do this I receive something like this:

```
gcloud.services.enable) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied to enable service [cloudaicompanion.googleapis.com]
Help Token: AZ-7fWIF20GK3ER1ViuaMH6ip69ELCf7tHmErk4aivL_6ab3r5oIDHdzl_sk9B2ec17Ongx-SI0JDZuFoQmZkRK2HvLWl...
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - subject: ?error_code=110002&service=servicemanagement.googleapis.com&permission=servicemanagement.services.bind&resource=resonant-gizmo-400216
    type: googleapis.com
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: serviceusage.googleapis.com
  metadata:
    permission: servicemanagement.services.bind
    resource: resonant-gizmo-...
    service: servicemanagement.googleapis.com
  reason: AUTH_PERMISSION_DENIED
```

I tried specifying all the project IDs i submitted when I signed up but no luck.

Comment: I get the same error (error_code=110002).
Help Token: AZ-7fWLFt6_Iq5WSqk6RmoW0h_3QAqCBHHaOYZJeGjcuL5peLvYmQ4lP0HBQ_5KQrPUgHIyiML_IFrFwDw3dddNimJXX_GbOdQr5Y_5EQ8X7APAX

Comment: UPDATE: activation was working for me today, but the code suggestions were really disappointing and pretty much useless.